# Trying to get Insights with FQL-query but getting no data

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-page

I'm trying to get some statistical data from my page using FQL like so:

```
SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=278942378807967 AND metric='page_fan_adds' AND end_time=1327903200 AND period = 2592000
```

However all that is returned is:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I also tried different dates and periods, most of which I'm pretty sure there should be data presented...

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a valid access token on your query to get the stats.

Answer (score 0):

`period` can only be `86400` or `period("day")`